# API Odata OR or IN operator

Tags: acumatica

version 22 R1

Is there any way to make a logical OR query to the contract-based API?  As far as I can tell it's not possible but, I wanted to check with the community.  So, a filter like this:

```
/Default/20.200.001/salesorder?$filter=OrderNbr eq 'SO006538' or OrderNbr eq 'SO006537'
```

is coming back with a HTTP 500 response "Only AND logical operator is supported".

I also tried this, which is coming back with a syntax error:

```
/Default/20.200.001/salesorder?$filter=OrderNbr in ('SO006537','SO006538')
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

try ( )

```
 ....$filter=(OrderNbr eq 'SO006538') or (OrderNbr eq 'SO006537')
```

example:

```
 http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=(FirstName eq 'Ronald') or (FirstName eq 'Russell')
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir.  I'm still getting "Only AND logical operator is supported" with an HTTP 500 response.

Comment: maybe not implemented in this API.  it worked for me on trestle API

Comment: see example in answer

Answer (score 0):

The 'or' has been implemented only from Acumatica 2022R2.

It is detailed in the section "Web Services: Innovations in the Implementation of the
REST API" of the developer release notes available here

https://community.acumatica.com/supported-releases-67/acumatica-2022-r2-downloads-and-release-notes-11493

The 'in' is not yet available.